# What is the fastest way to join DataFrames in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, performance, join, julia

Since Julia is really fast, I was wondering what the fastest way is to join data frames. For example, in R we may use the [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) package which is pretty fast. Sometimes when working with big datasets the computation time becomes high. Here I created a benchmark using `innerjoin` and `leftjoin`:

```
julia> using StatsBase, DataFrames, BenchmarkTools
julia> n = 1000000
julia> df1 = DataFrame(x = 1:n,
                       y1 = rand(n))
julia> df2 = DataFrame(x = 1:n,
                       y2 = rand(n))

julia> @benchmark innerjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 102 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  41.437 ms … 73.495 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 29.87%
 Time  (median):     45.926 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   49.160 ms ±  8.227 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  7.26% ± 11.50%

  ▄▅ █   ▂      ▂                                              
  ██▆██▅████▅▃▃▅█▆▁▅▁▁▁▁▃▃▁▁▁▁▆▁▃▅▁▁▁▃▁▅▅▅▅▃▁▁▃▁▃▁▃▁▁▁▃▃▃▁▁▁▃ ▃
  41.4 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        71.7 ms <

 Memory estimate: 38.16 MiB, allocs estimate: 174.

julia> @btime innerjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)
  41.592 ms (174 allocations: 38.16 MiB)

julia> @benchmark leftjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 96 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  43.823 ms … 79.582 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 34.30%
 Time  (median):     48.566 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   52.387 ms ±  9.026 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  6.74% ± 10.90%

  █▂▁▅▄▅                                                       
  ██████▅▃▆▆▃▃▅▅▆▆▃▁█▃▃▁▁▃▁▃▃▁▁▁▁▃▃▁▅▃▁▁█▃▃▃▃▅▃▁▁▅▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▃ ▁
  43.8 ms         Histogram: frequency by time        76.9 ms <

 Memory estimate: 39.23 MiB, allocs estimate: 230.

julia> @btime leftjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)
  44.198 ms (230 allocations: 39.23 MiB)
```

Here we can see that innerjoin is in this case slightly faster. So, I was wondering if there are faster ways of joining data frames in Julia?

Comment: It is not fully clear what you mean by "faster". I have benchmarked your example and on my machine DataFrames.jl performs the join example you specified roughly 2x faster than data.table. Still, most likely it is possible to perform this join even faster (every generic code like `innerjoin` or `leftjoin` in DataFrames.jl will be slower than custom written algorithm for your specific case, as generic code needs to do a lot of bookkeeping that can be skipped in custom code).

Comment: Hi @BogumiłKamiński, Yes you are right. I only wanted to mention that data.table is a fast option, but it seems that Julia is even faster. It is great to see that Julia has a lot of potential in performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the values in `:x` column in both data frames have the same sequence of values (which is happening in your case), then you can use [`hcat`](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/functions/#Base.hcat). I get a better result on `hcat` (**~24,500x** faster  **on average** without copying the data and ~7x faster with copying) ([note that you should prepend `$` to `df1` and `df2`](https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/#:%7E:text=if%20the%20expression%20you%20want%20to%20benchmark%20depends%20on%20external%20variables%2C)):

```
julia> @benchmark hcat($df1, $df2[!, 2:end], copycols=false)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 10 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  1.550 μs …  1.705 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 99.45%
 Time  (median):     2.440 μs              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   2.670 μs ± 17.047 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  6.35% ±  0.99%

  ▂█▇▆▁      ▁▂▂▃▄▁
  █████▅▄▃▄▆████████▇▆▅▅▄▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁ ▃
  1.55 μs        Histogram: frequency by time        5.72 μs <

 Memory estimate: 2.66 KiB, allocs estimate: 34.

# with copying
julia> @benchmark hcat($df1, $df2[!, 2:end])
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 633 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  4.387 ms … 50.850 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 86.24%
 Time  (median):     6.380 ms              ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   7.876 ms ±  6.799 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  17.48% ± 16.80%

  ▄▅██▅▃▂
  ███████▆▄▅▅▄▄▆▅▁▁▁▁▅▄▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▄▄▄▄▅▆▄▅▅▄▅ ▇
  4.39 ms      Histogram: log(frequency) by time     42.1 ms <

 Memory estimate: 22.89 MiB, allocs estimate: 64.

julia> hcat(df1, df2[!, 2:end]) == hcat(df1, df2[!, 2:end], copycols=false) == innerjoin(df1, df2, on = :x) == leftjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)
true

# Element-wise comparison (However, the above expression is enough)
julia> all(Matrix(hcat(df1, df2[!, 2:end]) .== hcat(df1, df2[!, 2:end], copycols=false) .== innerjoin(df1, df2, on = :x) .== leftjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)))
true
```

If I want to make a summary:

|  | Time | Memory |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hcat | ~24,500x faster | ~19,000x fewer |
| hcat(with copy) | ~7x faster | ~1.7x fewer |

*Note that the comparisons are against your best result, which is related to `innerjoin(df1, df2, on = :x)`

---

## Additional Note

Also, note that `@benchmark` contains comprehensive results, and it contains `@btime` as well:
[image]

So you don't need to necessarily run `@btime` to get it!